# How to use free download manager for downloading database from phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am trying to download a database which is very large in volume, so I am trying free download manager but it doesn't download the file, instead it downloads export.php.html.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your download manager is probably not supplying the correct authentication token or other POST parameters to phpMyAdmin. The file is dynamically generated based on the form you submit from the Export page. Try disabling your download manager and trying the download directly from your browser.

If you're concerned about the size of the file or getting timeouts, you could set [`$cfg['SaveDir']`](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_SaveDir) in your configuration file to a folder on your web server which allows you to save the file to that folder and then use whatever out of band means you wish (such as your download manager, scp, rsync, ftp, etc) to download the file. You should also see [these notes](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#web-server-upload-save-import-directories) about working with the UploadDir and SaveDir.